# APP NAME has encountered a user-defined breakpoint

Tags: c#

Out of nowhere, my app is start crashing with "APP NAME has encountered a user-defined breakpoint". I've never seen this error before and I've not touched the app for a year. And it was working without a problem. Now I rebuilt in development computer, checked many times. All assemblies are being built as x86 Release. But still same problem.

Anyway to solve this ?

Edit: I tried to debug, and found this

```
First-chance exception at 0x77a3f9f2 in APPNAME.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

I think it has do something with invalid handle is being specified but it doesn't show where and how come this same app was working for months without a problem.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: There is no stack trace :(. It just crashes with a Close Program and Debug buttons. When I click Debug. It crashes again, now no more Debug button.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some plugin used by any control which is out of dated or missing.

Comment: Its not problem from UI that Im sure of. Because Form appears perfect. Its an inside thread that is causing. But I dont know what in where.

Comment: try tracing debugging : http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2003/11/Code-diagnostic-an-article-on-tracing-and-debugging.aspx

Comment: Already have Trace in many places, but its not being written to file. Maybe thats the problem.